# How to get only few elements from the Array List of Objects in karate

Tags: karate, jsonpath

I have the following json:

```json
{
    "store": { 
        "book": [ { 
            "category": "reference", 
            "author": "Nigel Rees", 
            "title": "Sayings of the Century", 
            "price": 8.95 
        }, { 
            "category": "fiction", 
            "author": "J. R. R. Tolkien", 
            "title": "The Lord of the Rings", 
            "isbn": "0-395-19395-8", 
             "price": 22.99 
        } ], 
        "bicycle": { 
            "color": "red", "price": 19.95 
        } 
    }, 
    "expensive": 10 
}
```

I want to retrieve all the `books`' `author` and `category` in the following way:

```json
[ { 
    "category": "reference", 
    "author": "Nigel Rees" 
}, { 
    "category": "fiction", 
    "author": "J. R. R. Tolkien" 
} ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#json-transforms

```
* def fun = function(x){ return { category: x.category, author: x.author } }
* def books = karate.map(response.store.book, fun)
```

Comment: Above solution working as expected and solve my purpose .... [
  {
    "category": 7,
    "email": "michael.lawson@reqres.in"
  },
  {
    "category": 8,
    "email": "lindsay.ferguson@reqres.in"
  }]